# How to know the next method to execute after the main thread finishes executing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

In javascript, is there a way to know what method is gonna be executing after the main thread? . When i'm in the last line of the code, the Call Stack says this:

```
window.fbAsyncInit ((index):784)
window.FB.u.__wrapper (all.js:82)
(anonymous function) (all.js:120)
```

But when i go through with [image] three times the web loads completely without stopping, debugging it with chrome.

thanks for any help.

EDIT: I mean anyway with chrome's debugger

Comment: No, there is not a way to know what events or timers will fire after the main thread.

Comment: Excuse me, sarcasm?. Actually in the example above i found it but it took me a very hard work, with breakpoints everywhere and i'd like to know if there is a easier way.

Comment: Not meant as sarcasm.  From any thread of javascript code, there is no way to query the system to find out what event will happen next after this thread of execution finishes.  That isn't a feature that javascript has.  Of course, you can put breakpoints all over your code and discover what actually does happen next, but what event will actually happen next is not something you can query the system for ahead of time.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have to look through the whole code then or what do you recommend me to do?. Thanks